# Google Play autoupdate after permissions change

Tags: android, google-play

**The android developer documentation are pretty misleading and i can't seems to understand the bottom line.**

My app contain the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

And i need to add this new "normal" permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Will this effect users with autoupdate enable? would they need to accept app new permission?**

Google docs
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 3):

#### If you add a normal permission

The app is able to update without asking user for granting permissions.

[`CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) is a normal permission.

#### If you add a dangerous permission

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app.
>
> [...]
>
> - If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, **or** your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.
> - If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, **and** your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

That means users running Android 5.1 or older will not update the app automatically and will have to confirm new dangerous permissions before update. If your app has target SDK version lower than 23 users running Android 6+ will also have to confirm the update.